# CSS media query for exact viewport width

Tags: javascript, html, css

Using javascript I create a meta viewport and assign to it a value of 980px. The script is this:

```
var viewPortTag=document.createElement('meta');
viewPortTag.id="viewport";
viewPortTag.name = "viewport";
viewPortTag.content = "width=980, user-scalable=1";
document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(viewPortTag);
```

In CSS, is it possible to write a media query that fires only when the viewport width is EXACTLY 980px?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You could do something like this. The media query will be triggered at 980px width and would work for width no greater than 980px.

```
 @media screen and (min-width: 980px) and (max-width: 980px) {
     html {background-color: red !important;}
 }

 html {background-color: green; min-height: 300px;}
```

Answer (score 25):

Yes, in **CSS** it is possible to use `@media` rules to target an *exact* width.

### CSS Example

```
@media (width: 980px) {
  /* Your CSS */
}
```

This is telling the browser, when the **viewport** width is exactly `980px` wide, apply the following **CSS**. When your **viewport** `width` changes to `981px` or `979px` or anything that isn't `980px` wide, the **CSS** will be removed.

Unlike the other answers, this is not using `max-width` or `min-width` because the `@media` rules allow you to *just* define `width`, which will target the exact measurement you give it. The `width` is defined using the **viewport width**.

> **Note:** You can learn more about the **CSS3** `@media` rule from [W3 Schools](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_mediaquery.asp). Specifically if you look under **Media Features**, you'll see the available variables, including `width` all the way at the bottom.

Answer (score 8):

You can use the exact width like this:

```
@media screen and (width: 980px) { 
    /* CSS rules here */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

using both width and height exactly for ipad pro width:1024px, height:1366px

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 1024px) and (max-width: 1025px) and (min-height: 1366px) and (max-height: 1367px)
```

Answer (score -3):

```
@media screen and (min-width: 980px) {
  body {
      background-color: lightblue;
  }
}
```

Comment: I think it should be @media screen and (min-width: 980px), screen and (max-width: 980px)

Comment: if he needs exactly on 980 i.e. min and max both than yes it will be @media screen and (min-width: 980px), screen and (max-width: 980px) but in case after 980px also than my answer. anyway thanks